# nginx & fastcgi-mono-server: Error running dmcs: Cannot find the specified file

Tags: asp.net, nginx, fastcgi

I have been experimenting with nginx & fastcgi-mono-server4 (on ubuntu 11 natty) and was getting the following asp.net runtime error:

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.
System.SystemException: Error running dmcs: Cannot find the specified file

I was going to post this question to stackoverflow, but halfway through typing (and actually reading the message properly!) I figured out how to fix it. See answer.

Comment: Mono has been installed in /opt/mono-2.10 on my system, so I just needed to add /opt/mono-2.10/bin to the PATH environment variable & that solved it.

Answer (score 4):

See comment posted to original question

This solved it ...

$ PATH=$PATH:/opt/mono-2.10/bin